# AWS can't upload file

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, upload, awss3transfermanager

part 1:

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentials =   [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxx"       secretKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxxx"];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionAPNortheast1                                                                        credentialsProvider:credentials];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
[AWSDDLog sharedInstance].logLevel = AWSDDLogLevelVerbose;
[AWSDDLog addLogger:[AWSDDTTYLogger sharedInstance] ];
```

part 2:

```
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];

uploadRequest.bucket = @"bucket";
uploadRequest.key = @"tarpath";
uploadRequest.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: srcPath]; 

[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor]                                                      withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) { 

if (task.error) {
    if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) 

{return nil;}];
}
```

info.plist has prepared the ATS problem

Below is The error log:

> content-encoding:aws-chunked
>       content-type:binary/octet-stream
>       host:s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
>       transfer-encoding:Chunked
>       user-agent:aws-sdk-iOS/2.5.9 iOS/10.2.1 zh_CN transfer-manager
>       x-amz-content-sha256:STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD
>       x-amz-date:20170813T133010Z
>       x-amz-decoded-content-length:78670
>
> ```
> content-encoding;content-type;host;transfer-encoding;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-decoded-content-length
> STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD]
> 2017-08-13 22:30:10:521 test[1026:597507] AWS4 String to Sign: [AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
> 20170813T133010Z
> 20170813/ap-northeast-1/s3/aws4_request
> 7b0dac3ee72f93ad197c7dd6277c2cf5779e6f13c7009e405cafeb765c45eeb0]
> 2017-08-13 22:30:10:523 test[1026:597507] Request headers:
> {
>     Authorization = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxxx/20170813/ap-northeast-1/s3/aws4_request,
> ```
>
> SignedHeaders=content-encoding;content-type;host;transfer-encoding;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-decoded-content-length,
>   Signature=f91f3f9002bfe3ae7ec39c71846efd7c99bdf72d5f8163ac400d476f1055b7e7";
>           "Content-Encoding" = "aws-chunked";
>           "Content-Type" = "binary/octet-stream";
>           Host = "s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com";
>           "Transfer-Encoding" = Chunked;
>           "User-Agent" = "aws-sdk-iOS/2.5.9 iOS/10.2.1 zh_CN transfer-manager";
>           "X-Amz-Date" = 20170813T133010Z;
>           "x-amz-content-sha256" = "STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD";
>           "x-amz-decoded-content-length" = 78670;
>       }
>       2017-08-13 22:31:11:117 test[1026:597507] Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "要求逾時。"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x171056e90 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/zxmdata/thevoice/56334401838871229471503493680_Wanmei2017.aac,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/zxmdata/thevoice/56334401838871229471503493680_Wanmei2017.aac,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=要求逾時。}
>       2017-08-13 22:31:11.161499 test[1026:597374] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "要求逾時。"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x171056e90 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/zxmdata/thevoice/56334401838871229471503493680_Wanmei2017.aac,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/zxmdata/thevoice/56334401838871229471503493680_Wanmei2017.aac,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=要求逾時。}

Answer (score 1):

Error message says it is a [NSErrorFailingURLStringKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nserrorfailingurlstringkey?language=objc) error.

The url in error message has a typo, `-` in `https`:

`h-ttps://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/zxmdata/thevoice/56334401838871229471503493680_Wanmei2017.aac`